# css select :nth-of-child(1) not working

Tags: css, wordpress, selector

so im trying to make the first wide box under recent promotions (at the bottom) have a a bigger height than the rest of the boxes, however nth-of-child is not working, I just need it for that first wide box. here is the code:

```
#listify_widget_recent_listings-2 .job_listing-entry-header:nth-child(1) {
height: 400px !important;
}
```

When you remove the :nth-of-child it makes all the boxes bigger as expected in that widget so I am not sure why its not working for the first. Help!

Comment: You must include a [mcve], StackOverflow is not your debugger. And search before asking, there are already gazillions of questions about [:nth-child not working](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3Anth-child+not+working).

Comment: did you try my code which i answered?

Comment: @Oriol okay sorry dad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
#listify_widget_recent_listings-2 .job_listings li:nth-child(1) .job_listing-entry-header.listing-cover.has-image {
    height: 400px !important;
}
```

comment please if i miss something

Comment: thanks that worked!